# Difference between Copy Constructor and Assignment Operator?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy

I'm having a little trouble with Copy Constructor.

I have a class, which contains two structures, and two pointers to the first structure ( let's just say I'm having a Linked List of first structure, and each contains a linked list of the second structure ). They all seem to work fine. But ...

When I make another instance of the class using the copy constructor ( does a deep copy, every element is copied, so each instance has it's own linked lists ) using

`MyClass a,b;
// Operations with a
b ( a );`

it all works ok. But then...

`MyClass a,b;
// Operations with a
b = a;`

also seems to work, but then my destructor goes amok, and tries to free some element multiple times, sending this:

*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000258a540 ***

along with ==Backtrace== and ==Memory Map==, ending killing my program by SIGABRT signal.

So, when the copy constructor works fine and is present, what is wrong with assignment? Should I override the operator= ?

Comment: If you'd show use the code of `MyClass` this would be way more fruitful.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the code...

Comment: There's no way the first version works unless you have a call operator `MyClass::operator()(MyClass)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have defined a assignment operator explicitly, it is obvious that your code is broken.
A implicit assignment operator does member-wise assignment of each data member from the assigned object. If you have member variables that e.g. live on the heap the standard implicit assignment operator does not do a deep copy and only copies the pointer values.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the compiler uses the copy constructor implicitly with Assignment Operator.

Comment: You are welcome. The copy constructor is a "real" constructor and has nothing to do with operators. Have fun :-)

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor is used when you create a new object, specifying an object to copy, so

`MyClass b(a);`   (`MyClass b = a;` is the same)

Uses the copy constructor.

The assignment operator changes the value of an existing object, so in your case:

`MyClass b;`

Creates b and

`b = a;`

uses the assignment operator, which you haven't defined.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator are closely related. In fact, the idiomatic implementation of the copy assignment operator is **implemented in terms of the copy constructor**, which means that the copy assignment operator calls it internally. This is called the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Copy-and-swap).

It will also prevent strange errors cause otherwise by accidental self-assignment.